# Как с помощью match case проверить тип данных и присвоить в переменные?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.10

Как реализовать этот код с помощью `match, case`

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
if isinstance(a, list) and len(a) == 3:
    a1 = a[0]
    a2 = a[1]
    a3 = a[2]
```

Такой способ слишком громоздкий

```
match a:
    case list(a):
        a1 = a[0]
        a2 = a[1]
        a3 = a[2]
```

Такой просто проверяет, что это у нас коллекция

```
match a:
    case a1, a2, a3:
        print(a1, a2, a3)
```

Comment: А чего не используете более короткое присваивание`a1, a2, a3 = a`?

Answer (score 3):

Работает такой вариант:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]

match a:
    case list([a1, a2, a3]):
        print("List", a1, a2, a3)
    case _:
        print("Not matched")
```

- выведет `List 1 2 3`

Со значениями других типов, например:

```
a = (1, 2, 3)

match a:
    case list([a1, a2, a3]):
        print("List", a1, a2, a3)
    case _:
        print("Not matched")
```

- выведет `Not matched`

Со списком длиной не равной 3 (например, `a = [1, 2, 3, 4]`) также выведет `Not matched`.

Comment: Конечно, есть вопросы, почему так работает. Видимо сначала значение a целиком проверяется на list, а потом уже распаковывается на отдельные элементы, т.е. выражение `list([a1, a2, a3])` обрабатывается как бы снаружи-внутрь

Answer (score 2):

```
match a:
    case [a1, a2, a3] if isinstance(a, list):
        print(a1, a2, a3)
```

Но это не сильно элегантнее чем

```
if isinstance(a, list) and len(a) == 3:
   a1, a2, a3 = a
   print(a1, a2, a3)
```

Comment: Там есть способ через типизацию, то есть в нормальной ситуации list(a), это приведение переменной а к списку, но в случае c match case эта вещь проверяет тип данных, а не приводит. Я думал с помощью этого можно решить эту задачу. Но спасибо за предложение.